# SQL query frouping - how does the following work?

Tags: sql

I am trying to get a Cutting Group within cutting list(CutGroup).

Master Table - Tab1:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6adMJ.jpg)

I am looking sum (Qty) in each group (ID, GroupSLN, MaxLen, Len, Reminder) and keep each group structure(Group) as it is. This is code which I've tried so far:

```
SELECT        ID, GroupSLN , MaxLen, Len, Reminder ,Sum(Qty),   max(SLN) AS SLN
FROM          Prd300_OPT
            GROUP BY BarID,  Bar, Length, Reminder, BarSizeID, SessionID ,Cuts 
            ORDER BY SLN
```

Comment: Could you please describe what do you want to do in order to obtain the "Desired results" table? Like, I dunno, grouping IDs and counting the number of matches between ID and GroupSLN, or whatever.

Comment: Sir, Thanks your replay .... i am looking sum(Qty) in each group(ID, GroupSLN, MaxLen, Len ,Reminder) and keep each group structure as its..

Comment: You appear to want to block by id and maxlen but don't have a tidy way of doing that. Can you add sample data as text to the question please.

Comment: Why is this tagged mysql *and* sql-server? Only tag the database you're using.

Comment: Conflicting RDBMS's removed. Please add back only the tag of interest.

Answer (score 0):

The id and maxlen seem the columns of importance. Using a sub query I can downfill the maxlen and use that to join back to the main table in a sub query to get the sum of qty over id and maxlen.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(id int,maxlen int,len int, reminder int,qty int,sln int auto_increment primary key);

insert into t (id,maxlen,len,reminder,qty) values
(1,100,1000,null,1),(1,null,1000,1100,null),
(2,200,2000,null,1),(2,null,2000,2100,null),
(2,200,2000,null,1),(2,null,2000,2100,null),
(2,200,2000,null,1),(2,null,2000,2100,null);

select id,maxlen,len,reminder,
        case when s.qty is not null then
            (select sum(qty) from t where t.id = s.id and t.maxlen = s.lastmaxlen)
        end as qty
from
(
select distinct
         id,maxlen,len,reminder,qty,
        case when maxlen is null then
        (select 
        maxlen from t t1 where t1.sln < t.sln and t1.maxlen > 0 order by sln desc limit 1) 
        else maxlen
        end as lastmaxlen 
from t
) s
;

+------+--------+------+----------+------+
| id   | maxlen | len  | reminder | qty  |
+------+--------+------+----------+------+
|    1 |    100 | 1000 |     NULL |    1 |
|    1 |   NULL | 1000 |     1100 | NULL |
|    2 |    200 | 2000 |     NULL |    3 |
|    2 |   NULL | 2000 |     2100 | NULL |
+------+--------+------+----------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Notice the use of the distinct clause to dedupe in the sub query.